# dotdotdot JS Plugin not wroking correctly for Japanese language

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotdotdot

I am using Jquery plugin dotdotdot.. (http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).
I am facing some issues with it.

When I am applying it on my long text in Japanese, it is not working correctly and showing blank instead of truncated text.

I am using wrap:word.

Text I am using is : 筋肉のブレを抑え、さらなるパフォーマンスをサポート独自の段階着圧により効果的に筋肉のブレを抑える高機能ソックス

Expected result : it should show truncate result but its showing blank.

Can anyone please suggest on it..

Regards,
Ritesh

Comment: Correction: Using wrap : letter

Comment: Isn't CSS only using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` a solution in your case? Can you replicate issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: Issue can be reproduced here. http://jsfiddle.net/RgHRs/191/

Comment: Is that what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/RgHRs/192/  I'm sorry, not speaking/writing japanese, not sure what to expect here

Comment: Your solution is good but at the current stage I can't change the approach and have to stick on plugin usage.

Comment: You should read this link and see examples, maybe more fitting your needs: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed as of version 1.6.9.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgHRs/194/)

However, it is still not working properly if there is a space at the beginning of the sentence.

**Works:**

```
<div id="wrapper">筋肉のブレを抑え、さらなるパフォーマンスをサポート独自の段階着圧により効果的に筋肉のブレを抑える高機能ソックス</div>
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
<div id="wrapper"> 筋肉のブレを抑え、さらなるパフォーマンスをサポート独自の段階着圧により効果的に筋肉のブレを抑える高機能ソックス</div>
```